# convert GPCC precipitation data

Tags: data

maybe someone has already worked with the GPCC precipitation data from this site: ftp://ftp-anon.dwd.de/pub/data/gpcc/html/fulldata_download.html

and knows how i can convert this strange format to a data type which is readable by GDAL (like netcdf)?

Martin

Comment: This is several years ago, but maybe someone who wants to use GPCC rainfall data as Netcdf or Geotiff and googeled it, may find this post useful: http://matinbrandt.wordpress.com/2013/09/04/79/

Answer (score 3):

https://wiki.zmaw.de/mpimet/GpccAnalysis features a Python script converting GPCC data format to netcdf.

Comment: Hallo underdark, thanks for the link. This works fine, but only with the data from the visualizer which can be saved in a ArcView Ascii format and not with the full dataset. The problem with this script is, that every single month has to be visualized, saved, and converted, which takes a lot of time if you need 100 years..

Answer (score 1):

If the data are the same as on this site: http://www.esrl.noaa.gov/psd/data/gridded/data.gpcc.html (currently, the DWD FTP is down), then you need to compile GDAL with netCDF support to read the data. At least, NOAA offers GPCC in netCDF format.