# Coordinate problem with GPCC netcdf data and QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, latitude-longitude, netcdf

[image: screenshot of issue]I downloaded Global Precipitation Climatology Centre (GPCC) monthly precipitation data in netCDF format from here: https://www.esrl.noaa.gov/psd/data/gridded/data.gpcc.html

According to the site, they should be in WGS-84 projection:

However, when I open the file in QGIS, the latitude values all show up as negative.

How do I fix this using QGIS?

Comment: Maybe related: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4725/convert-gpcc-precipitation-data and https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/37790/how-to-reproject-raster-from-0-360-to-180-180-with-cutting-180-meridian . I get longitudes between 0 and 360, but not negative.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Sorry, I meant latitude (really jetlagged today!).  The latitudes are all reported as negative by QGIS when I pan around the map with the cursor (range -180 to 0).  The file is already netCDF.

Comment: The data (I downloaded the first dataset in the list from the link) is displaying correctly in ArcGIS 10.5.1 so it looks like it's not a general problem with the file.

Comment: Thanks.  Seems to be a QGIS bug then...  Could you (or anybody else) kindly export that first file in another format that QGIS can read correctly?  That file is the one I need, and I only need it for 2011-2016 (which makes the size much smaller). Many thanks if that is possible!

Comment: I just downloaded ftp://ftp.cdc.noaa.gov/Datasets/gpcc/combined/precip.mon.combined.total.v7.nc amd ran `gdal_translate -b 1000 precip.mon.combined.total.v7.nc p1000.tif` which produces a tif between 0 and 360 longitude, and latitudes between -90 and 90. Both tif and netcdf fit to Natural Earth shapefiles. I'm not sure what you did wrong.

Comment: In QGIS, this still has the wrong latitudes for me.  I added a screenshot above to illustrate.

Comment: I'm running QGIS 2.18.10, maybe the error has been fixed since 2.18.0. Please run `gdalinfo -nomd p1000.tif` to see what extent GDAL reports.

Comment: The layer extent reported for the layer properties is as below: Layer Extent (layer original source projection)
0.0000000000000000,-180.0000000000000000 : 360.0000000000000000,0.0000000000000000

Comment: If you run gdal_translate and gdalinfo in the OSGEO4W shell as written above, do you get the same extent?

Comment: Thanks.  I found another rainfall dataset in another format, and decided to give up on this one.  Hope that this issue is resolved in 2.18.10!